# Form error mapping on collection

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3

I have a form:

```
class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('autor', AutorType::class)
            ->add('categories', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => CategoryType::class,
                'error_bubbling' => false,
            ))
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Article::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

This embeds to a custom form. my Article entity looks like this:

```
class Article
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Type(type="AppBundle\Model\Autor")
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    private $autor;

    /**
     *
     * @Assert\All({
     *     @Assert\Type(type="AppBundle\Model\Category")
     * })
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    private $categories;
}
```

My problem is  a category field error (category name not blank for example); the error is never mapped to the field itself.

With `'error_bubbling' => true`,the error is map with ArticleType form.

With `'error_bubbling' => false`, the error is map to the collection 
CollectionType but never to the CategoryType form or name filed of CategoryType.

I am on Symfony 3.3 and can not use `cascade_validation`, I use `@Assert\Valid()` but it don't seem to work as I expected.

Where did I do wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Valid()` as form constraint instead of class one. (Be sure to remove class `Valid` constraint)

Just encountered same thing and after like 20 combinations it was the solution for me. I'm on symfony 3.2 though.

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Valid;

class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('autor', AutorType::class)
            ->add('categories', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => CategoryType::class,
                'error_bubbling' => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new Valid(),
                ],
              ))
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Article::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `error_bubbling` option to the collection entries. Not the collection itself. Because the error does not happen to the collection but to the category item in the collection.

```
$builder
    ->add('autor', AutorType::class)
    ->add('categories', CollectionType::class, array(
        'entry_type' => CategoryType::class,
        'entry_options' => [
            'error_bubbling' => false,
        ],
    ))
    ->add('submit', SubmitType::class)
;
```

Or set it as default in your `CategoryType`:

```
// AppBundle\Form\Type\CategoryType.php
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Category::class,
        'error_bubbling' => false,
         // maybe other options
    ]);
}
```